# Как редактировать макросы в notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, макросы

В notepad++ можно записывать макросы, точно так же, как и в MS office. Можно ли потом как-то редактировать этим макросы вручную? На каком языке в notepad++ записаны макросы? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Будет интересна любая информация на тему создания и редактирования макросов в notepad++, может, есть какие-нибудь книги или подробные статьи на эту тему?

Comment: Сам пользуюсь npp, но мне че-то советовали в сторону [sublimetext 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) смотреть.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Да, макросы можно редактировать вручную.

> Текст макроса хранится в файле
> shortcuts.xml. А вот где хранится
> shortcuts.xml – зависит от вас. Если
> при установке поставить галочку “Don’t
> use %APPDATA%”, то файл будет
> находиться в Program Files, в
> противном случае – в Document and
> Setings/%USERNAME%/Application
> Data/Notepad++.

Записанные макросы хранятся в формате **XML**.
Почитайте вот эту статью: "**[Редактирование макросов Notepad++](http://softboard.ru/topic/72229-notepad-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/)**"

По запросу **[макросы Notepad++](http://bit.ly/15QaLw1)** в поисковой выдаче есть даже видеоматериалы.

Comment: Да я видел, просто думал, может, есть какие-нибудь полноценное руководства, типа книги.